Text to Image overlay with GD library -- how to add HTML in the text?
Using GD library to add text into an image which works fine.. but now I want to add HTML tags to format the text.  Is this possible? If so how?  I have tried this but the HTML is not being parsed, just passed into the image:
GD img script:
<?php
header("Content-type: image/png");
$string = $_GET['textOverlay'];
$im     = imagecreatefrompng("soldier.png");
$orange = imagecolorallocate($im, 220, 210, 60);
$px     = (imagesx($im) - 7.5 * strlen($string)) / 2;
imagestring($im, 3, $px, 9, $string, $orange);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>

and the HTML code in a separate file:
<p><img src="texttoimage.php?textOverlay=This <u>is</u> Text <b>For</b> You"></img></p>

thanks

Well, images aren't rendered as HTML documents, so I don't know why you'd ever expect this to  work? You'd have to use something else to pre-render that text using a HTML rendering engine, somehow get a screenshot of that rendered HTML output, and then use that in your image. I suspect this is not an optimal approach for your scenario.

You can do a limited amount of formatting with https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php
